# how to counter the string occurrence in a csv file's column

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file in that file I need to counter the occurrence of the string.

for example this is a sample file

```
column_A
Abhi
Spidy
Abhi
Max
```

so in the above csv file I need to have to following the output:

```
output:
Abhi 2
Spidy 1
Max 1
```

Hi have tried with this

```
import csv
import collections

data = collections.Counter()
print(data)
with open('file.csv') as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=';'):
        data[row[1]] += 1

print('%s' % data['columnA'])
print(data.most_common())
```

Comment: `row[0]` if you want the first column, indexes start at `0` not `1`

Comment: Thank you, but I need to check with the column not with row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I see you did it using counter, Ive used pandas just to read the csv file:

```
dict_final = {}
list_intermed = []
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
for i in df.A:
    if i in list_intermed:
        dict_final[i] += 1
    else:
        dict_final[i] = 1
        list_intermed.append(i)
print(dict_final)
```

Which will give the output in the form of a dictionary

---

Using only CSV module :

```
import csv
list1 = []
final_dict = {}
list2 = []
with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     csv_obj = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     for row in csv_obj:
        list1.append(', '.join(row).split()) #so we get a list of all rows
for i in list1[1:]: #excluding the first row as those are column names
    if i[0][:-1] in list2: #i[0][:-1] takes the rows first element till the second last character the reason we take second last character is so that we don't include a comma that comes in the list items (rest of the code is same)
        final_dict[i[0][:-1]] += 1
    else:
        final_dict[i[0][:-1]] = 1
        list2.append(i[0][:-1])
```

Comment: Thanks Aryan, but what is the if i in l1:

Comment: Oh thats a typo, i reformated the variable names to make it more understandable, must have left that one out, let me just make a quick edit

Comment: do you have the answer with csv module

Comment: Sure, edited my answer (I literally just looked up the documentation for csv module, so this might not be the best code)

Comment: you made my day bro, I don't know this code will be working or not but thanks for your effort.